# Getting posts from google plus page

Tags: api, rss, feed, google-plus

I would like to get content (posts) from a google+ page and post it to my website, as a feed. Is there any info how?

I read that current API does not allow that, but those topics were from the last year.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I found it.

http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-php-starter/

and this

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

The only problem is that you need to log into your google app to do this. Any sugggestions would be apprecited.

Comment: As Gus said above, authenticating is not required.  If you establish a Plus Client, using your API key, you will be able to make these API calls without having to be logged into Google+.

Answer (score 10):

You can perform [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list), without having to authenticate, by passing your "simple" key from the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) for a project created that has the Google+ service turned on. Access to the API calls is restricted to the authorized origins you set up in your project.

After you create the project, in the section "Simple API Access" there is an API key. Build your client with this key, your client id, and client secret:

```
<?
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    $plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
    $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities("+GooglePlusDevelopers", "public");
?>
<html><body><pre><? echo print_r($activities);?></pre></body></html>
```

A final note, make sure you use the [latest Google+ PHP client](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/).

Comment: in current google php client this file not included,,,,,,,    
Google_PlusService.php,,,,,,,
From where to get full library?

Answer (score 2):

Updating the correct answer, the class name has changed to Google_Service_Plus

```
<?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ .'/vendor/google/apiclient/src');
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
    $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities("+GooglePlusDevelopers", "public");
?>

$items = $activities->getItems();
foreach($items as $item) {

   $object = $item->getObject();
?>

<div class="gpost">
   <p><?php echo $object->getContent(); ?></p>
   <a href="<?php echo $item['url']; ?>">Read more</a>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```